# How to compare values in a dataframe with a list of numbers?

Tags: python

I have dataframe:

```
id  max_days
11  0
22  1
33  2
44  4
55  5
```

Also, I have a list:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I need to take the **column max_day** and compare it with **every element in the list**: if max_day >= element in the list then **count(id)**.
For example, 1st value in the list = 0, and all ID from dataframe have max day >= 0. Then we have count = 5

As a result, I need the next dataframe: value from list and counts from dataframe

```
value   count
0       5
1       4
2       3
3       3
4       2
5       1
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "if max_day >= element in the list then count(id)"?

Comment: I need to take all values from the list and count how many times IDs from the dataframe satisfy the following condition: max day >= values from the list. For example, 1st value in the list = 0, and all id from dataframe have max day >= 0. Then we have count = 5. Is it clear now?

Comment: how come count = 5?

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can use list comprehension to build a list of tuples, then give it to pandas to initialize your DataFrame.

```
# Just building the data
df=pd.DataFrame({"max_days": [0,1,2,4,5], "id": [11,22,33,44,55]}).set_index("id")
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# list comprehension into a DataFrame
pd.DataFrame([(v, (df.max_days>=v).sum()) for v in my_list]).rename(columns={0: 'value', 1:'count'})
```

### Result

```
   value    count
0      0        5
1      1        4
2      2        3
3      3        2
4      4        2
5      5        1
```

### Explanation

This list comprehension generates a list of tuples understood by pandas DataFrame.

The conditional statement returns an array of boolean. When summing it, the boolean values are evaluated as integers with `True=1` and `False=0`. Therefore, the result of `sum()` means the count of True.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
import pandas as pd

l=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
max_days=df.max_days

d={i:sum(1 for k in max_days if k>i) for i in l}

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

df.columns=['count']

>>>print(df)

   count
0      5
1      4
2      3
3      2
4      2
5      1
```